# Is there a simpler way to edit values based on a character in sql?

Tags: sql, casting

I have a column named `population` which is a text type because it cannot convert those values with a comma to a `numeric` as seen below. I used the following query to select those: `select population from total_table where population like '%,%'`. Is there an efficient way in SQL to remove this comma so I can cast it to a `numeric` type without using an `update` query for each value?

[image]

Comment: You can use: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_replace.asp, and https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_cast.asp. If you know it is going to be used as a numeric value, you should have another column, where you also store the numeric values for read, and make sure that it always gets updated with the text value. It would be better not to use the text column at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use replace function to remove comma as shown below:

```
select replace(population,',','') from total_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to update the value you would use:

```
update total_table
     set population = replace(population, ',', '')
     where population like '%,%';
```

Then you can alter the type of the table.  In most databases, this looks something like:

```
alter total_table alter population int;
```

Or `numeric` or whatever type you want.